# Божеский, божественный, или Как уйти от тавтологии?

Tags: грамотная-речь, тавтология, паронимы

> Почти **божеские почести**, которые воздавались Цезарю ещё при жизни
>   как потомку Венеры и как завоевателю далёких, сказочных стран – Галлии
>   и Британии, теперь, посреди этого страшного волнения, **привели к**
>   народному **требованию обожествить его**.

Что должно быть, по задумке, вместо *божеские*?

Почести - воздают(ся)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почти **божеские** — можно в этом контексте, как мне кажется, заменить на **высочайшие** (но без "почти")  или **небесные** (или немного с другим акцентом — **вселенские, всесветные**).

**воздать почести**
[**Синонимы**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/245334/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C): встать на колено, преклонить колени, оказать почести, преклонить голову, преклонить колено, почтить, встать на колени.

[**Воздать**](https://difficult_words_ru.academic.ru/416/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)
Оценить по заслугам в знак признания.
Воздать добром за зло, воздать должное, воздать кесарю кесарево, воздать почести.

*Объявлялся порядок вещей, в котором по суровому чину им надлежало иерархически следовать непосредственно за Господом Богом, а военному полю **воздавались почести**, подобающие небу на Ильин день.*
Б. Пастернак

*Хотя государыня строго приказала, чтобы при каждом случае ее сыну **воздавались почести**, подобающие его положению, и сама настойчиво следила за точным исполнением предписаний этикета при всех официальных торжествах...*
Г. Самаров